# Cannot syncronise pgp keys with server

Tags: 12.04, pgp, keyserver

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 I am unable to synchronize my PGP keys with the keyservers.
I have tried keyserver.ubuntu.com and pool.sks-keyservers.net
The error message I get is:

```
Couldn't retrieve keys from server:keyserver.ubuntu.com
Couldn't communicate with server 'keyserver.ubuntu.com': Internal Server Error
```

Any suggestion or help?

Thanks!